# How to pass parameters in axios url?

Tags: ruby, axios

I am trying to use Axios in my Ruby Sinatra Project.
There is a url defined in my ruby file.

```
post '/follow/:id' do
# do something
end
```

In my erb file, I am trying to pass the variable in view to my inline script.

```
<body>
    <div id="follow_element">
        <button v-on:click="followUser">Follow</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            const app = new Vue({
                el: "#follow_element",
                methods:{
                    followUser(){
                        axios.post("/follow", {
                            params: {
                                id: <%= @user.id %>
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

What I want is if the user click the button, the app would hit the /follow/:id url to update result. However, I met two problems. 
First, the <%= @user.id %> doesn't work (@user is a variable available in this erb). The second is the app hits the '/follow' endpoint, instead of '/follow/:id' endpoint.

Could you please give me some suggestions? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that as you wrote this:

```rb
post '/follow/:id' do
# do something
end
```

You'll now accept POST requests like: `/follow/oneRandomId`, `follow/124184965` and so on...

Right here, you are making a request to `/follow`, passing POST params that is not in url. This will not work:

```js
axios.post("/follow", {
  params: {
    id: <%= @user.id %>
  }
})
```

In order to fix it, you can generate an URL with the available `@user.id` and make the POST request, like this:

```
axios.post("/follow/<%= @user.id %>")
```

Or, if you want to pass some data to the user (POST data, not URL params), you can do this:

```
axios.post("/follow/<%= @user.id %>", {
  name: 'A beautiful name to insert to an user with that ID'
})
```

If you're still getting stuck, you can also use `axios(config)`, that I think a bit clearer about what it is doing, from [axios README page](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig):

```js
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: "/follow/<%= @user.id %>",
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have struggled on this for the whole day. I really appreciate your help.